# Spring Integration Error/Exception handling

Tags: java, spring-integration, google-cloud-pubsub

I have started working with Spring Integration to send messages to external System using Spring Integration Google Pub/sub model.

I am sending the payload received by the Service activator as below

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel")
              public void messageReceiver(final String payloadMessage) throws IOException {
    adapter.sendData(payloadMessage);  // send payloadMessage data to external system, add exception handlers
}
```

What I want is to implement Exception Handling to the adapter.sendData(payloadMessage) such that I would like to consider varies scenarios like

1. External System down
2. Network issues connecting to network from my system to external system.

I have been following the below Google cloud documentation and other online documentation but have
not found sufficient usecase to handle the above scenarios
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/spring#using-spring-integration-channel-adapters

Considering the above scenarios I would like to implement exception handling such a way that data is not lost when there are exceptions and external systems should receive data even if there are exceptions after some period of time.

I have configured the below error channel. Now there is any error in the sendData() method, I see the same failure messages keeping on loading in the eclipse console. Is there any need to add the param `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.max-ack-extension-period` in the yaml

```
 @Bean
public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(final @Qualifier("myInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
        PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) 
{
    PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, pubSubSubscriptionName);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
    adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO_ACK);
    adapter.setErrorChannelName("pubsubErrors");
    return adapter;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubErrors")
public void pubsubErrorHandler(Message<MessagingException> exceptionMessage) {

    BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage originalMessage = (BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage) exceptionMessage
            .getPayload().getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE);

    originalMessage.nack();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need some retry and backoff logic around your exceptions.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain.

The `@ServiceActivator` has that `adviceChain` attribute for your consideration.

Comment: tx, any implementation example if available if shared it will be very helpful. Why is the above have lot of xml configuration?

Comment: The framework was developed originally on the XML DSL. We slowly works on providing Java and other DSL code snippets into docs. See some Java DSL sample here: https://github.com/artembilan/microservices-patterns-spring-integration/tree/main/circuit-breaker

Comment: Do I need to implement the circuitbreaker? There aren't multiple microservices involved. Only a call to the external system from the subscriber(which receives message from the queue )

Comment: No, you don't need. You asked for a sample and I showed you the closest one. There is just no way to have samples for every single use-case.

Comment: understood. One question here is how can we ensure the data is sent from the subscriber to the external system(after it is working condition from failur) after exception is thrown.

Comment: I'm not sure in your question. First of all you probably talk about a `producer` - the `sendData` is producing, not consuming. If you don't have an exception on that `sendData`, then your data is probably produced to the external system.

Comment: let me clear you, sendData() sends data to a external system which is basically a restAPI exchange call. This method is called inside a subscriber code (messagereciever() in this case a pubsub consumer). The payload is already published in the queue which the messageReciever() method has processed and is sending to the external system using the sendData() method.

Comment: You probably can just re-throw an exception back to Pub/Sub and let it to nack that message, so it can be retried again by the consumer. Still not clear what you'd like to see when no exceptions...

Comment: I would like to see only in exception scenarios. Not when there are no exceptions. Can you please provide the link where in I can check for how to nack the message

Comment: Well, the tutorial you share in your question has the pointer to respective type: `BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage`. However I believe Pub/Sub does a nack automatically when we throw an exception.

Comment: I have tried configuring this scenario with the below documentation, What i see that the console logs keep on pritinings without stop. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#error-handling

Comment: I don't know what are "console logs" and what they keep printing. Would you mind to share more info? For example an EDIT in your question would be great

Comment: Added the piece of code which was causing repeated loading of logs in the eclipse console. Actually I was using the same input channel for 2 external Rest API calls.  Is there any way through which we can use the same channel for sending various kinds of data through HTTP endpoints(GET,PUT,POST,DELETE) to external systems

Comment: You don't show what logs. You can use the same channel as log as it is a `PublishSubscribeChannel`.

Comment: No subscribing to same channel for two different different external endpoints from the serviceexecutors,  is calling both the endpoints. I am trying to call only POST method (sendData()) but another service executor which calls external deleteData() method is also getting called as both of them are subscribed to same channel. Is it i need to create new seperate channels for different calling different http methods?

Comment: If your `inputChannel` is a `DirectChannel`, then you are doomed: it works in round-robin manner by default. If you want to send the same message to several subscribers, then `PublishSubscribeChannel` is for you. Please, consider to raise a new SO question since this goes out of original subject already.

Comment: I have created a new SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75377542/spring-integration-how-to-send-messages-from-pubsub-subscribers-to-external-sys