# Spring Integration: How to send messages from pubsub subscribers to external systems/servers with Http Methods

Tags: java, spring-integration, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been trying to send messages to external systems(using rest template POST, PUT etc) from the service activators as below.

Below is my pubsub consumer class

```
public class MyConsumer{

    @Autowired
    ExternalService externalService;

            @Bean
        public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(final @Qualifier("myInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
                PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) 
        {
            PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, pubSubSubscriptionName);
            adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
            adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.AUTO_ACK);
            adapter.setErrorChannelName("pubsubErrors");
            return adapter;
        }


        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubErrors")
        public void pubsubErrorHandler(Message<MessagingException> exceptionMessage) {

            BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage originalMessage = (BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage) exceptionMessage
                    .getPayload().getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE);

            originalMessage.nack();
        }


         @Bean
          public MessageChannel myInputChannel() {
             return new DirectChannel();
           }

            @Bean
            @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myInputChannel")
            public MessageHandler messageReceiver_AddCustomer() {
                return message -> {
                      externalService.postDataTOExternalSystems(new String((byte[]) message.getPayload());
                      };
            }

            
            @Bean
            @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myInputChannel")
            public MessageHandler messageReceiver_DeleteCustomer() {
                return message -> {
                   
                    externalService.deleteCustomer(new String((byte[]) message.getPayload());
                    BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage originalMessage =
                          message.getHeaders().get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE, BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage.class);
                    originalMessage.ack();
                };
            }
}
```

`ExternalService` below is the service which sends data to the external systems.

```
public class ExternalService{
            
            void postDataTOExternalSystems(Object obj){
            // RequestEntity object formed with HttpEntity object using obj(in json) and headers 
              restTemplate.exchange("https://externalsystems/",HttpMethod.POST,requestEntity,Object.class);
            }
            
            void deleteDatafromExternalSystems(Object obj){
            // RequestEntity object formed with HttpEntity object using obj(in json) and headers 
              restTemplate.exchange("https://externalsystems/",HttpMethod.Detele,requestEntity,Object.class);
            }
    
}
```

Since both the methods messageReceiver_AddCustomer and messageReceiver_deleteCustomer are using same channel whats happening is when I try to just addcustomer, the deleteCustomer is also called by default.

I was thinking of creating a seperate channel for deleteCustomer, but creating in this way leads to creating channels for every usecase.

Hence would like to know three things here.

1. Is there is any other approach of sending through Spring integration through which I can send data to external systems using a single Channel or a different utilization of Channels.
2. If any error in the external service calls leads to unending of failure logs in the console

   ```
    message_id: "6830962001745961"
    publish_time {
      seconds: 1675783352
      nanos: 547000000
    }
    }, timestamp=1675783353720}]': error occurred in message handler
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is your expectation for such a logic. You have two contradicting subscribers for the same input channel. It sounds more like you need a router first to determine where to proceed next with an input message from Pub/Sub: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#messaging-routing-chapter.

> but creating in this way leads to creating channels for every usecase.

Sure! You can go without Spring Integration and just do everything with the plain `if..else`. So, what's a difference? Therefore I don't see a reasonable argument in your statement. Yo have different HTTP methods, and that is OK to map them via Spring Integration router to respective sub-flows. The `MessageChannel` is really first-class citizen in Spring Integration. It makes a solution as loosely-coupled as possible.

Several subscribers on your current `DirectChannel` will lead to a round-robin logic by default, so you'll be surprised that one message from Pub/Sub creates a customer, another deletes and so on in rounds. The `PublishSubscribeChannel` will make it bad as well: both of your subscribers are going to be called, so created first, then deleted immediately.

Comment: My expectation is a loosely coupled environment. Since my system is integrated to external system, any issue with external system should not hamper my services. Hence I push the customers data to queue and consume from the queue and send to the external system from the subscriber. In the routing example I was not able to find any HTTP method usecases and any external URI as well. can you please highlight which section i can find

Comment: Well, that doc is just generic one to make you familiar with router pattern. It is really up to your application logic to determine what part of input message to use for routing key. According to your current code there is no distinguishing when to call create and when delete. So, everything is out of our control at the moment. Please, share more info how you'd like to determine which HTTP method to call against that Pub/Sub consumed message?

Comment: Well on my end I am sending customers data to a external system. When there is new customer/s at my end, I send list of newly created customers to the external system and same goes with the delete, when a customer/s is removed from our system, we inform the external system that these customers are removed from our system. Inorder to have a loose coupled integration, I am using a pubsub. Here I first publish the list of customers I have created at my end into the pub/sub and then consume the list as a payload and send the payload to the external system. Same goes with the delete.

Comment: Basically my system is not connecting directly with the external system but a message pubsub helps sending the data. But my job will be both publish and subscribe and then send to the external system. same way goes with the external system. I receive data from external system and keep into the pubsub and then consume from the pubsub to process at my end. The pubsub is helping me to create a loosecoupled environment

Comment: That's all good, but I don't see how can you understand if you need to call `postDataTOExternalSystems` or `deleteDatafromExternalSystems` ?

Comment: yes thats the factor here i am not able to utlize the capabilty of pubsub with these usecases. How do i implement these using pubsub is a brainstroming thing for me since couple of days

Comment: Well, you probably can publish those `create` and `delete` requests into different topics. You also can add an extra header into the message you publish. Then on the consumer side you can use that header for routing. In case of different topics you just can have different subscribers and therefore different channel for different service methods in the end.

Comment: yep I thought the same. Is this the best solution.  Thing is there will be bulk of topics for different service calls. Fair enough, how do i deal with the continuous loading of error logs on the STS eclipse console?. I am not able to look into those logs and distinguish whether i am still able to get the messages from pubsub when there is an errror in the subscriber

Comment: I think this is just a retry Pub/Sub built-in :it does not pull a new message until it is done with the current one. No? Do I miss anything? You can implement a retry with backoff as we discussed in other your question on a service level.

Comment: " it does not pull a new message until it is done with the current one " but for long does it do? is there any way to stop processing after some period of time?

Comment: That's I cannot answer. I believe there should be an option like `redelivery attempts`.

Comment: can i use IntegrationFlow to send payload to external systems?

Comment: The `IntegrationFlow` is just a syntax sugar to make developer life easier. In the end you still need to use some service method for your business logic.